# How to remove all lines with caps AND digits AND special characters AND all the lines longer than 10 characters from a text file?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file with all existing words in the Dutch language and I need only the words with a specific amount of characters, without any digits or special characters or capitals. I tried to do it by hand (which works) but it's about 400 thousand words :) So I wanted to use Python. I'm very new to Python and I can't find a good solution.
With my code (which is far from optimal) I get results but not good enough. Some words seem to be split halfway and concatenated, in some lines two words are not put on a separate line (to name a few things that I don't want).

My question: Is there a simple code that can remove words longer than 10 characters, remove all words starting or containing a Cap, remove all words with special characters? Thank you all in advance.

My code:

```
import re

input_file = open("basiswoorden-gekeurd.txt", "r+")
output_file = open("word_crumble_wordlist.txt", "w")
filetext = input_file.read()
res_caps = re.sub(r"\s*[A-Z]\w*\s*", " ", filetext).strip()
res_dig = re.sub(r"\s*\d\w*\s*", "", res_caps).strip()
res = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]\w*\s*", "", res_dig).strip()

for line in res:
    if len(line) < 10:
        output_file.write(line)
```

Original part of word-list:
[Original: see the numbers and special characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKXbE.png)

Resulting part:
[Result: looks ok but the word "aaaaagje" seems a combination of other words :) HOW?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCb96.png)

Also:
[Original, with "aanbevolencomité AND aanbevolen" as two separate words on two separate lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6sxz.png)
And:
[See "aanbevolencomitaanbevolen"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imJgR.png)

Comment: It would be easier for us to reproduce if you provided a small example of the textfile in your question to be copy pasted.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it might be easier to *find* matching words, rather than *delete* unwanted, consider following example let `file.txt` content be

```
Capital
okay
thisistoolong
okaytoo
d.o.t.s
```

then

```
import re
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.read()
for i in re.findall(r'^[a-z]{1,10}$',text,re.MULTILINE):
    print(i)
```

gives output

```
okay
okaytoo
```

Explanation: I use `MULTLINE` line mode so `^` and `$` mean start of line and end of line, then I am finding lines which contain from 1 to 10 lowercase ASCII letters.

Comment: Thx @Daweo. It worked great. I only changed the print into someoutputfile.write(i). That made it print lines with concatenated words. So I added "\n" after the i and now I got a text-file with the words I wanted, they way I wanted. Thanx again!